# Important fields in HTTP header from security perspective

Tags: web-development, security, http-headers

What are the Important fields in HTTP header from security perspective? I tried to google it but unable to find. Can anybody provide me a link to read about it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the Important fields in HTTP
>   header from security perspective?

When it comes to security, the safest response is to consider *everything* while placing priority on the things which attackers are known to exploit.

The headers which your server returns on a request are important to attackers ([particularly](http://www.evolt.org/node/60160) fields which expose the software/version information about your webserver or otherwise allow the attacker to profile the server). (... and +1 for John Conde's mod_header directives on this point - definitely doesn't hurt to tell client browsers to enforce CSRF/XSS policies)

The headers which your webserver and application accept with a request (i.e. anything that your webserver or application has to parse) are important to you because (a) your webserver will probably make an effort to parse all of them - which may provide the attacker a means for executing a [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) or [slowloris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris) attack - and (b) your application needs to sanitize and/or validate (as in the case of a cookie which may have been modified) anything used as an input.

Comment: Cookies can be quite big (up to 1.2MB), but I think slowloris attcks and buffer overflows in headers are more the purview of web server developers. I suppose your application could receive a buffer overflow from parsing header data, but most web languages are high level languages not susceptible to this. That's not to say that PHP or a PHP library itself might not have a buffer overflow vulnerability. But keeping things up to date is all you can really do here.

Comment: If you're interested in learning more about buffer overflows as they apply to web apps, read this PDF: http://adventuresinsecurity.com/Papers/WebAppSecurityBuffOverflows.pdf

Comment: *@Lèse majesté* - You're absolutely correct - protocol-level exploits are generally directed at the webserver daemon are typically outside the purview of web devs who aren't doing the full-stack thing ... though it certainly couldn't hurt for web devs to have a feel for the "bigger picture" of security - i.e. "this is why you can't trust variables stored in cookies"

Answer (score 7):

Here's some I use:

```
# Don't allow any pages to be framed by my site or any others
# Defends against Clickjacking!
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY

# Only allow JavaScript from the same domain to be run.
# Also, don't allow inline JavaScript to run. 
Header set X-Content-Security-Policy "allow 'self';"

# Turns on IE 8 XSS prevention tools
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"

# Don't send out the Server header. This way no one knows what 
# version of Apache and PHP I am using
Header unset Server
```

Useful inks:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/the_x-frame-options_response_header
  https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/CSP/Specification
  http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Web%20Search/thread?tid=187e02e745a50a77&hl=en

Comment: These headers may also be relevant in case you _do_ want to allow some cross-domain AJAX calls: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Comment: Note that there are some non-malicious web services that display your site within an IFRAME. Setting `X-Frame-Options` is a problem with those services. See the following: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/31289/9876

Answer (score 2):

You also want to make sure important cookie headers are sent with the `HttpOnly` option.

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

There are ways to force this externally using [ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/), apparently, and of course you can (and should) set it from within application code that sets cookies.

Comment: I totally forgot cookies are included in the header of a request

Comment: @john see http://lcamtuf.blogspot.com/2010/10/http-cookies-or-how-not-to-design.html