# Is there any good reason I would want my website to be framed?

Tags: security, iframe

I'm building a website that's not security-critical in any way at all, so having somebody put a page in an `<iframe>` is not particularly dangerous to its users. However, as my website doesn't have script plugins that will be used anywhere else, is there any reason why I shouldn't just apply:

```
X-Frame-Options: Deny
```

to every page on my website? Is there any valid reason for any other website to embed mine? I've seen plenty of content-stealing ones and attempts to hijack user accounts, but never an actual good usage of frames that's not an explicit feature of the website.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some folks get a fair amount of traffic by allowing themselves to be framed by social network sharing sites like [StumbleUpon](http://www.stumbleupon.com/) - if your page is at all likely to be shared, I'd avoid doing this, and handle instances of framing in another way.

Also, your site can already be sucked in and repurposed by benign services like [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) - and I believe an HTTP header like that won't prevent that kind of usage.